# Pandas DataFrame Conditionally Merge

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two dataframe condiitonally with below scripts:

```py
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1','A1', 'A2'],
 'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2','C3']})

dfc = dfa.merge(dfb)

for i in range(len(dfc.index)):
    if dfc['A'][i]==dfc['A'][i+1]:
        dfc.drop([i], inplace=True)
```

But there is a `KeyError: 4` error message:

```py
In [38]: runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Administrator\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 18, in <module>
    if dfc['A'][i]==dfc['A'][i+1]:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1071, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 4
```

Besides, when I checked the `dfc` value, row 1 was already removed:

```py
In [30]: dfc
Out[30]: 
    A   B   C
0  A0  B0  C0
2  A1  B1  C2
3  A2  B2  C3
```

However, if I coded line 12 `dfc.drop([i], inplace=True)` without `inplace=True`, I will get below with error too.

```py
In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
    A   B   C
0  A0  B0  C0
1  A1  B1  C1
2  A1  B1  C2
3  A2  B2  C3
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It will drop but the problem is

```
 dfc['A'][i+1]
```

When you print
`(dfc['A'][i])` => it will give you 0 - A0,1 - A1,2 - A1,3 - A2.

So when you compare values like:

```
dfc['A'][0] == dfc['A'][1]
dfc['A'][1] == dfc['A'][2]
dfc['A'][2] == dfc['A'][3] 
dfc['A'][3] == dfc['A'][4]
```

But there is no `dfc['A'][4]` value in your DataFrame. Thats whats its saying KeyError : 4.
In short `dfc['A'][i+1]` is out of Index when i = 3.